# "Unexpected EOF while parsing" while storing in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, eof

I am trying to parse data from server and want to store it in file but I am getting Unexpected EOF while parsing. I am very newbie on python.

Here is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.couponindia.in/";
r= requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"id" : "container"})

for item in g_data:
    print (item.text.encode('ascii','ignore'))
    with open('d:\\test.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(item.text.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Please give me any reference or hint.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `;` at the end of line 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to add a closing bracket.

```
f.write(item.text.encode('ascii','ignore'))
                                          ^
```

or

```
with open(r'd:\test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(item.text.encode('ascii','ignore'))
```